# Formatting Phone Numbers - CSV and Regex

Tags: python, formatting

I am just starting out with Python, so I am trying to play around with a few things to continue learning. I have pulled and printed the specific data needed from a CSV file. But the phone numbers all print in different formats.
How can I print them in all the same format, like say xxx-xxx-xxxx?

```
import csv
import re

with open("customerdata.csv", "r") as csvfile:
   reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
   for row in reader:
       if row['Purchases Past 6 Months'] > "0":
           phone = row['Phone']
           print(row['Name'] ,"|" ,row['Gender'] ,"|" ,row['State'] ,"|" ,row['Credit Card'] ,"|" ,row['Phone'] ,"|" ,row['Spent Past 6 Months'] ,"\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After:

```
phone = row['Phone']
```

add:

```
phone = re.sub(r'[^\d]', '', phone) # removes everything except digits
assert len(phone)==10               # ensures all numbers have 10 digits
row['Phone'] = re.sub(r'(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})', r'\1-\2-\3', phone) # formats the string
```

Or, without `re` module:

```
phone = ''.join(c for c in phone if c.isdigit())
row['Phone'] = '-'.join([ phone[0:3], phone[3:6], phone[6:] ])
```

BTW, I would also recommend replacing this:

```
print(row['Name'] ,"|" ,row['Gender'] ,"|" ,row['State'] ,"|" ,row['Credit Card'] ,"|" ,row['Phone'] ,"|" ,row['Spent Past 6 Months']
```

with:

```
fields = ['Name','Gender','State','Credit Card','Phone','Spent Past 6 Months'] 
print('|'.join((row[field] for field in fields)))
```

Comment: Thank you! - One other thing, when I run my original code, I am able to pull 100's of rows of data, but the phone numbers are not formatted. When I run after formatting the phone number, I only print one row of data. Am I missing something? I used the `phone = re.sub` method.

Comment: Probably indentation error; all the lines in all my snippets should be indented exactly like the `phone = row['Phone']` line… If not that, check if all your numbers really have 10 digits (or just remove the `assert` statement and see what happens).

Comment: Nevermind, I realized what I had done, thanks for your help! I had my `if` statement before the `re.sub` . Now it is formatting and running properly. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the cleanest way, but you could create a function to format it the way you want:

```
def formatPhoneNbStr(num_str):
    digits = ""
    for c in num_str:
        if(c.isdigit()):
            digits = c+digits
    return digits[0:3]+"-"+ digits[3:6]+"-" + digits[6:]
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help!